# Calculated fields using views or persisting them in the database

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'd like to know which is better to use, a database view or simply persist fields in the database.

For instance, I'm initializing `win_count` in the following view `vw_stats`:

```
...
CASE
    WHEN game.in_decision = true AND game.user_score > game.opponent_score THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END AS win_count,
...
```

Which is then mapped to a domain class:

```
package com.x

class Stat {

    //fields here...

    static mapping = {
        table 'vw_stats'
        version false
    }
}
```

Or, should I persist the field `winCount` in the database using this domain class and manipulate it before saving?

```
package com.x

class Game {

    //fields here...
    Short winCount = 0


  static constraints = {
      //constraints here...        
      winCount nullable: false, range: 0..99

  }

  def beforeInsert(){
      this.beforeUpdate()
  }

  def beforeUpdate(){

      //other manipulations here...
      if inDecision and userScore > opponentScore
          winCount = 1
  }
```

}

The issue with the view I find, is that it will generate a table when running the application and then I have to manually remove the table and run the code to generate the view.

**Update #1**
There might be an IO cost saving by persisting them in the database instead of the view?

**Update #2**
Forgot to mention, I should be able to apply an aggregate function on the resulting field in a service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A third approach is to use a [derived](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/GORM.html#derivedProperties) property. Like the view, the value is calculated on the fly.

```
package com.x

class Game {

    //fields here...
    Short winCount = 0

  static constraints = {
      //constraints here...        
      winCount nullable: false, range: 0..99

  }

    static mapping = {
        winCount formula: 'CASE WHEN in_decision = true AND user_score > opponent_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END'
    }

}
```

Comment: Oh, you should retain from asking for recommendations on stack overflow. It's not allowed.

Comment: Will I be able to apply a count (or any aggregate function) on winCount using a criteriaQuery though?

Comment: Yes. It's available like any other domain class property. The only time the wincount will not work is in unit testing.

Comment: How about portability? I suppose, if I don't use proprietary statements/keywords/etc, it should port well to other database systems if the opportunity presents itself.

Answer (score 0):

Not fully understanding the exact application you are trying to achieve, have you thought about using [transients](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/transients.html) and letting the domain instance calculate it when it is actually needed?  This will avoid pre-calculating data that may not even be used.